# Node update in Marklogic DB

Tags: xml, marklogic

I have multiple employee xml document saved in ML DB with the doc uri (/employee/*.xml), I want to take update from new XML where unique reference key is roleID (in ML XML its roleID and in new XML it is newroleID). Whenever match is found it should update ML xml's firstName value with new XMl's newFirstName, lastname value with newlastName, dep with new dep and rest of the xml structure should remain same.

Marklogic XML structure is as follows:

```
    doc uri /employee/1.xml
    <employee>
        <firstName>Jim</firstName>
        <lastName>Day</lastName>
        <dep>IT</dep>
        <city>Boston</city>
        <roleID>1111<roleID>
        <internalID>2222</internalID>
    </employee>

    doc uri /employee/2.xml
    <employee>
        <firstName>Jan</firstName>
        <lastName>Silly</lastName>
        <dep>Finance</dep>
        <city>DC</city>
        <roleID>3333<roleID>
        <internalID>4444</internalID>
    </employee>

    doc uri /employee/3.xml
    <employee>
        <firstName>Jack</firstName>
        <lastName>John</lastName>
        <dep>HR</dep>
        <city>Virginia</city>
        <roleID>5555<roleID>
        <internalID>6666</internalID>
    </employee>
```

I am trying this but not sure how to update document, also it doenst seems to be optimized xquery, please help.

```
    let $newXML := <employees>
                        <newemployee>
                            <NewfirstName>New Fname1</newfirstName>
                            <newlastName>New Lname1</newlastName>
                            <newdep>New Dep1</newdep>
                            <newcity>Boston</newcity>
                            <newroleID>1111<newroleID>
                            <internalID>2222</internalID>
                        </newemployee>
                        <newemployee>
                            <newfirstName>New Fname2</newfirstName>
                            <newlastName>New Lname</newlastName>
                            <newdep>New Dep</newdep>
                            <newcity>Boston</newcity>
                            <newroleID>5555<newroleID>
                            <newinternalID>6666</newinternalID>
                        </employee>
                    </employees>
    for $oldXML in doc("/employee/*.xml")/employee
        where $newXML/newemployee/newroleID eq $oldXML/roleID
        return
          for $Matched in $oldXML
            return
            let $finalXML := 
                (: Not sure how to update some nodes in given URI, where rest of structure remain same :)

                <employee>
                    <firstName>{$newXML/newemployee/newfirstName/text()}</firstName>
                    <lastName>{$newXML/newemployee/newlastName/text()}</lastName>
                    <dep>{$newXML/newemployee/newdep/text()}</dep>              
                </employee>
```

Answer (score 3):

See [xdmp:node-replace](http://developer.marklogic.com/pubs/4.2/apidocs/UpdateBuiltins.html#xdmp%3anode-replace)

From the documentation example:

```
(: insert the doc :)
xdmp:document-insert("/example.xml", <a><b>bbb</b></a>);
(: replace the b node in the doc with this c node :)
xdmp:node-replace(doc("/example.xml")/a/b, <c>ccc</c>);
doc("/example.xml") => <a><c>ccc</c></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `doc("/employee/*.xml")` doesn't work. Using `xdmp:directory` would, provided the directory is created (automatically or manually). Alternatively you could use `cts:uri-match` to find uris for employees, and pass those is a single blow to `doc()`, provided URI lexicon is enabled.

But.. the biggest bottle-neck in your approach is walking through ALL documents. That is not necessary. If roleID is unique, then use that for the uri, so you won't need to walk all docs, just open the correct one immediately. Alternatively, use an expression that can be optimized by the XQuery processor, or simply relies on indexes. Something like the following:

```
doc()[//roleID = $newRoleID]
```

Or:

```
cts:search(doc(), cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("roleID"), $newRoleID))
```

For the updating itself you could use `xdmp:node-replace` and related as suggested by @sgarrett, but you could also simply recreate the entire XML, and use xdmp:document-insert to replace it entirely. The document is replaced entirely behind the scene anyhow, so you will hardly notice any difference with such small documents.

HTH!

Comment: I would imagine that cts:search is faster than doing `doc()` with a predicate, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @sgarrett depends highly whether or not the optimizer sees it can be optimized or not. May need some fiddling with the exact syntax. Functions like `xdmp:plan` help with that, but timing should say enough as well. If optimized the XPath route performs equally fast as the cts:search route. They mean exactly the same.

Comment: `xdmp:directory("/employee/", $depth)` does *not* require directory-creation, neither manual nor automatic. It uses the universal index. See http://blakeley.com/blogofile/2012/03/19/directory-assistance/